# iPhone app to manage MySQL databases

Tags: applications, mysql

Is there any app for iPhone where I can manage my server's MySQL databases?
Or any app to just create an entire MySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

I've used MySQL QueryDB Client in the past. It has been my favorite iPhone app for MySql after testing out quite a few. It is certainly not perfect but it gets the job done when I need it to. I wouldn't recommend using this full time, only for backup.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mysql-querydb-client/id576948046?mt=8

Good luck!